# How does x86 northbridge/memory controller routes addresses for memory mapped io?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, io, x86

My current understanding is that northbridge/memory controller routes address accesses, based on some programmable rule, such that accesses to memory mapped region will be re-directed to southbridge and relayed to devices, while RAM will not even notice these memory accesses. Is this correct, and if so, how does it do it?

Comment: RAM is a "device" too ... generally speaking, the memory controller is programmed (usually by the boot code, not the linux kernel) with a set of mappings from physical address to bus address + device enable (aka "chip select").

Comment: @MurrayJensen thanks. Is there some kind of 'routing table' to tell memory controller that 'hey, these regions are reserved for pci devices'? Where does that table live? I guess this table should probably be implemented by a small memory/cache rather than a few registers since it could be bigger than a few rows. but I do not know for sure, and even if it is true, where does it live? inside memory controller?

Comment: Yes. The "table" lives inside the memory controller hardware. In general terms, it is usually a bunch of registers, one per "chip select" ... the hardware designer wires these chip selects into the chip enables of the devices on the bus, along with the address and data lines. The memory controller registers usually have a base address and size and other bits to do with the bus transfers (width etc) and when the mc sees an access from the cpu that is within the range and size it asserts the corresponding chip select and routes the address and data onto the a/d lines of the bus.

Comment: @MurrayJensen thanks again. If they are indeed implemented by registers, then that means the number of mmio ranges will be a limited number? if I do `cat /proc/iomem` on linux box it shows dozens of disconnected regions, that means there are that many registers to deal with them?

Comment: I/O space is implemented differently to memory mapped devices - access is done by special instructions and does not go through the memory controller... But yes there are a limited number of chip select mappings in the memory controller.

Comment: @murray maybe i'm wrong but i thought `/proc/iomem` shows the memory mapped addresses rather than i/o space?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right, sorry ... You have to interpret the contents of /proc/iomem with regard to your architecture, but likely a lot of those disconnected regions you mention are serviced by a single chip select, for example if the device is a bridge to a bus that has its own address space